# Log4j: Logger stops working after load third party jar

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j, slf4j

Logger suddenly stops working after call a method of third party jar. I have checked code of jar, they are also using log4j with log4j.xml. I am configuring log4j by using the properties file.

**My log4j configuration**

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, R
#log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, stdout, R
log4j.appender.R.File=/logs/app_test.log
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=175
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p %t %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
```

**Third party logs configuration (log4j.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<!--Pattern used: Date Thread_Name Full_Class_Name.Method_Name Level:Line 
    no -->
<!-- %-23d{ISO8601} [THREAD:%t] [%-2c.%M():%L] [%p] - %m%n -->


<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">


    <appender name="consoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern"
                value="%-23d{ISO8601} [%-5p] [%-22t] [%-30C{1}:%4L] - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="errorAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File"
            value="${catalina.base}/logs/metascan/metsascanWrapperError.log" />
            <param name="maxFileSize" value="10MB" />
                    <param name="Threshold" value="ERROR" />
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="2" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy MM dd HH:mm:ss:SSS} [%-40t] %5p - %m %n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="infoAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File"
            value="${catalina.base}/logs/metascan/metsascanWrapperInfo.log" />
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="10MB" />
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="2" />
        <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern"
                value="%-23d{ISO8601} [%-5p] [%-22t] [%-30C{1}:%4L] - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>


    <appender name="debugAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File"
            value="${catalina.base}/logs/metascan/metsascanWrapperDebug.log" />
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="10MB" />
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="2" />
        <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern"
                value="%-23d{ISO8601} [%-5p] [%-22t] [%-30C{1}:%4L] - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>


    <category name="com.xerox.metascan" additivity="true">
        <priority value="ERROR" />
        <appender-ref ref="infoAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="debugAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
    </category>

    <!-- <category name="org.springframework"> <priority value="error" /> <appender-ref 
        ref="infoAppender90" /> <appender-ref ref="errorAppender90" /> </category> -->
    <root>
        <priority value="error" />
        <appender-ref ref="errorAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />

    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

I have read the configuration on log4j website, preference will always go to log4j.xml over properties file. So, I don't want to change in the third party jar. I am assuming that they are overriding my log4j configuration but I don't know the exact issue because even system.out.println doesn't work.

So how we I resolve the issue, is there any way I can ignore the third party logs configuration?

Any suggestions will be helpful, Thanks.

Comment: Did you try specifying it explicitly with a command line argument, like: `-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties` ?

Comment: Yup, but not working for me. Checked it with by adding VM arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, You cannot ignore the third party logs, You can override them by loading externally log4j configuration.

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
```

but ideally, this is not a good practice. You should tell them who provided you the jar and they should fix that because any third party jar should not affect your configuration.